# How to change button image in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I am working on an app which has a button. The button has no text, image or background.

So what I want to do is to give it an image in the viewDidLoad function.

This is what I have:

```
@IBOutlet var tapButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tapButton.setImage("redTap.png", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

But I have an error that says I can not convert string to UIIMage.

How do I get it to work?

I have tried:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "redTap.png")

tapButton.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I have gotten it to work but now I have a problem.

The image is suppose to be a red text but it shows up blue.

I was able to get the image to show correctly by using:

```
let image = UIImage(named: imageColor[randNum])?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
tapButton.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

What I want now is to not have the button be highlighted when the button is pressed. I have a few other buttons that have images assigned to them in xcode and not through code. They don't highlight when pressed.

So how can I get rid of highlighting when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need ".png".

If ".imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)" is working for you: To keep the same image in different states, you have to set the same image/properties for the different states.

```
@IBOutlet var tapButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tapButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "redTap")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal), forState: .Normal)
    tapButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "redTap")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal), forState: .Highlighted)
}
```

Comment: It is working now but instead of showing a red button, which is what the image is, it shows a blue one. How do I get it to show the original image?

Comment: Updated the code to show how to keep it the same in different states.

Comment: You don't need to set two states. If nothing else is set, all states use the same image as used for the "normal" state.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3

```
yourBtn.setImage( UIImage.init(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

now (swift 3 edition):

```
@IBOutlet var tapButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tapButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "redTap")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    tapButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "redTap")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First I would put the image you wanted inside the Assets.xcassets folder. Just drag it in. Then you can call it whatever you want by double-clicking on it. Lets say that it is called "redTap".

For code you would put:

```
@IBOutlet var tapButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let redTapImage = UIImage(named: "redTap")
    tapButton.setImage(redTapImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's one simple solution:

```
@IBOutlet var tapButton: UIButton!{
didSet{
let image = UIImage(named: imageColor[randNum])
tapButton.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Besides that, in the Attribute Inspector, Set Button type to 'Custom'

Comment: Is that in order to prevent the button from highlighting when pressed?

Comment: I have tried using the code you provided but now the images don't even show up.

Comment: Do you set the button type to custom?

Comment: @user2303213 it works just fine on my Mac The version of Xcode is 7.3.1 The swift is 2.2

Comment: Don't forget to add the IBOutlet from your button.

Comment: I have already answered this question on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57676289/11228616

Answer (score 1):

First set your button type as `Custom` in interface builder and set the image for normal state for your button.

[image]

Connect IBOutlet for button in class file as

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnCheckbox: UIButton!
```

in your class file in `viewDidLoad` set image for selected state as

```
btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "name_of_image"), for: .selected)
```

Create `@IBAction` for in class file as

```
@IBAction func onTapCheckBox(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Then connect `@IBAction` to your button's `Touch up Inside` event from interface builder

Answer (score 0):

Let image = UIImage(named : "redTap.png")
tapButton.setImage(image, .Normal)

Comment: Is your image inside XCode image.assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
let image = UIImage(named:"redTap")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
button.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update For latest swift versions,**
It works this way

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "propopup")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: [])
```